# Recover from exceptions in ExecutorService

Tags: java, multithreading, executorservice

I use a the ExecutorService to execute my logic. As shown below , the run method should execute in a infinite loop. In short the run method is a message consumer which should remove messages from a queue and process the messages. However, the doSomething() method encounters an Exception, and never returns. After analysis, I realise that there was a NullPointer somewhere in the doSomething() method. While, I have taken care of that exception, how do I ensure that loop never terminates in-spite of any runtime exceptions. I cannot afford my Runnable task to be non-functional. It stops the entire functionality.

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    service.submit(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          while(true){
           doSomething();
       }
    }
  })
```

Comment: Seems like an abuse of ExecutorService. Why not just create your own Thread?

Comment: @dnault Why is this a abuse? Isn't this a better way of doing things?

Comment: Perhaps "abuse" is too string a word. But the ExecutorService isn't adding any value here. ExecutorService is commonly used as an abstraction when you have several tasks you want to run, and the code that submits the tasks to the service doesn't care about the details of how they are executed. But here you have a single task that just loops forever. Any attempts to submit other tasks to the executor will block forever since the looping task never finishes.

Comment: @dnault The real code is a bit different. The real code pulls out messages from a PriorityBlockingQueue in the infinite while loop (doSomething). This also means when there are no messages, it goes in to blocking mode (take). The nature of my module is to pick up a single message from the queue and process it. I don't need my messages to be processed in multiple threads. Therefore if you observe, I have used SingleThreadExecutor which serves my purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try catching exception within your loop like below:

```
ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
service.submit(new Runnable(){
    public void run(){
      while(true){
       try {
            doSomething();
       } catch (Exception e) {
           //log exception etc...
       }
   }
}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just surround the run method's content with a try/catch that catches every exception.

```
 ExecutorService service = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()
    service.submit(new Runnable(){
        public void run(){
          while(true){
             try {
               doSomething();
             } catch (Exception e) {
               handleException();
             }
       }
    }
  })
```